# Adjust font size Safari sidebar Mojave

Tags: terminal, safari, mojave, font, system-settings

does anyone know how to adjust the Safari sidebar font size? I called Apple Tech Support and they confirmed there is no user access to modify font size in the Safari sidebar, as you can for Finder, Mail, iTunes, etc. Any other ideas — terminal or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no.

I tried, and failed, to adjust the font size for a visually challenged client, but was unable to find any way to do it.